# Change theme(css) for SonataAdminBundle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3, symfony-sonata

I cannot install [RaindropSonataThemeBundle](https://github.com/raindropdevs/RaindropSonataThemeBundle) cause it only supports `SonataAdminBundle` up to `2.1.*@dev` and I am using a newer version. How can I install a different twitter bootstrap theme as Sonata reads its css from the vendor directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may override the `standard_layout.html.twig` template file to use your custom theme, as well as all layouts from the SonataAdminBundle.

Those files are configurable here:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
        history: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history.html.twig
        preview: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:preview.html.twig
        delete:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:delete.html.twig
        batch:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__batch.html.twig
        acl:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:acl.html.twig
        action:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:action.html.twig
        select:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__select.html.twig
        dashboard:           SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig
        search:              SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig
        batch_confirmation:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:batch_confirmation.html.twig
        inner_list_row:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_inner_row.html.twig
        base_list_field:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
        list_block:          SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig
        user_block:          SonataAdminBundle:Core:user_block.html.twig
        add_block:           SonataAdminBundle:Core:add_block.html.twig
        pager_links:         SonataAdminBundle:Pager:links.html.twig
        pager_results:       SonataAdminBundle:Pager:results.html.twig
        history_revision_timestamp:  SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history_revision_timestamp.html.twig
        short_object_description:    SonataAdminBundle:Helper:short-object-description.html.twig
        search_result_block: SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig
```

See http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html for more information.